# RoR... my scaffold table doesn't fill when i use radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, schema, radio-button, drop-down-menu, scaffold

I have a problem, i made a scaffold, generating the table "requirements", i want the user to fill the fields of the table in the edit and the new requirement with select boxes and radio buttons. The select box and the radio buttons appear in the explorer but when i select one option or one button, that value selected it's not reflected in the db. The code im using its the next: (As you can see i used the original cicle f.label(:notif_card) and f.text_field(:notif_card) generated by the scaffold, but i deleted the last one and used the select box in this case.)

```
<%= f.label :notif_card %><br />
<% value = { "Good" => 0, "In Progress" => 1, "Denied" => 2 }%>
<%= select( @requirement, :notif_card , value) %>
<% if value == 1 %>
  <% @requirement.notif_card = 1 %>
<%end%>
```

I just want to delete that text_field and replace it with a select box! Everything you can do i will appreciate it alot! If something needs to be in the model or in the controller besides the code that i'm using please let me know. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use the radio buttons for storing values from form to DB you can use the radio buttons..
 the syntax will be like

```
<b>notif_card</b><br/>
<%= f.radio_button:notif_card,'0'%>Good<br\>
  <%= f.radio_button:notif_card,'1'%>In progress<br\>
  <%= f.radio_button:notif_card,'2'%>Denied<br\>
  <%= f.submit %>
```

this will store values on the database by using radio buttons.
if you want to use check box method for the same, you can use but it is of Boolean method.so needs to be declared as boolean when start generating scaffolding it.